# OnMouseover - Hidden Tooltip for a particular series with C3 library

Tags: tooltip, c3

I have a LineChart with two simple lines, I have to have the possibility to hide the tooltips (render a line not selectable) for a particular series. Is it possible to achieve it with some apis provided?

I'm trying to develop my particular behaviour:

```
onmouseover: function (d, node){
                if (d.id=="Requested")
                {
                    __  what here?
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding the if statement in the content generator.

```
tooltip: 
        {

            contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) 
            {
                var $$ = this, config = $$.config, CLASS = $$.CLASS,
                titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
                nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
                valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
                text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;

            // You can access all of data like this:

                var count=0;
                for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) 
                {

                    **if (d[i].id=="Requested")** {
                    if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }

                    // ADD



                    if (! text) 
                    {

                        var formats=d3.time.format('%Y%m%d');
                        var date= new Date(formats.parse(scene[d[i].index].date));

                        title = date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+1+"/"+date.getFullYear();
                        text = "<table class='" + CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
                    }


                      }//if requested
                }
```